# Alternative Option For Panel Tabs?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, game-development

I'm working with a Windows Forms Applications, and I'm currently just making a little game launcher. I'm new to C# and Visual Studio as a whole so this question might sound silly, or it may not.
Here is my question though. I was wondering if there was an alternative to using panels to make pages, or tabs. I've seen on the internet that using panels for pages or tabs is a bad practice.

I want a button that opens a new page or tab. I found this program a while ago, and it's basically what I'm looking for, except for the tab-looking design.

***[Example]***
[image]

***My Program***
[image]

I want the 'Settings' button to open a new tab inside my program like the example program I showed.

The example program is called, "BF3 Settings Editor" if you download it you'll have to click the options button in the lower right hand corner, and then click on the drop-down box for Theme, and select the Dark Theme.

Okay, I hope I explained that well. It's been bothering me for a while, I can't seem to figure out how else to do this.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: You must be looking for this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21489/Creating-a-Multi-Page-Windows-Forms-Control-with-D

Comment: If you just want to open a pane in your form, code it as a `UserControl` which you add to the `Controls` in the contructor of your `Form` with `Dock=Fill` and later  `BringToFront` and `Show` and `Hide`. Just make sure to think about the place where you store the settings! UCs are like `Forms` meant to sit inside `Forms`. [Here is a walk-through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240516/changing-and-passing-content-inside-tabcontrols-tabpage/23241088?s=10|0.3317#23241088)